# Two playes have same straight but one has two cards of it in hand

Tags: rules, reading-hands

Table cards: 5:spades:6:hearts:7:spades:8:hearts:2:spades:

P1 hand: 9:hearts: 6:spades:

P2 hand: 9:diamonds: 3:spades:

Both players have the same straight.
Is this a split?
Or does P1 win because he has 2 cards of the straight directly in his hand while P2 only has the missing 9? Are cards which are in hand prioritized over cards on the table?

Comment: I knew this rule. Was not sure if this was an exception though. Thanks anyway!

Comment: There are no exceptions to the top five cards rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a split because both player have the same hand. best five of seven cards to make your best hand is absolute in Hold'em. Rather you use one card, two cards or no cards from your hole cards it is still the best five of seven cards.